# Unable to access sub.

Tags: ssl, nginx, server, subdomain

Recently updated ssl certificate
main domain works properly but sub domain isnt working. below is the error.

Forbidden
You don't have permission to access / on this server.
Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Nginx server

Comment: We need more details of your configuration. Did you change more than just the X.509 certificate? Did you change any bindings or filesystem permissions? Is anything displayed in nginx's log files?

Comment: i used online generator to generate csr. I didn't change any filesystem permissions